# Create SQLite TABLES dynamically?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an app for streaming videos. In my app I have DB and a TABLE "SAVED PLAYLISTS". When user clicks on button "SAVE PLAYLIST" it saves playlists into that TABLE.
I need to create new TABLE now, user clicks on video "SAVE VIDEO" and chooses PLAYLIST where to be saved, if there are no playlists, he needs to create one. So it's something like this:

```
TABLE SAVED PLAYLISTS

TABLE_ID | TABLE_NAME | TABLE_DATA
         |            |


TABLE SAVED VIDEOS

VIDEO_ID | VIDEO_NAME | VIDEO_DATA | PLAYLIST_ID 
         |            |
```

I have the following code for my TABLE of SAVED PLAYLISTS:

```
    private static final String SELECT_PLAYLISTS_SQL_QUESTION = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseDefinition.TABLE_SAVED_PLAYLISTS;
```

```
 public void insertNewPlaylist(String playlistName, String playlistData) {
        ContentValues contentValuesNew = new ContentValues();
        contentValuesNew.put(DatabaseDefinition.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_NAME, playlistName);
        contentValuesNew.put(DatabaseDefinition.COLUMN_PLAYLIST_DATA, playlistData);
        try {
            openWritableInstance();
            databaseInstance.insert(DatabaseDefinition.TABLE_SAVED_PLAYLISTS, null, contentValuesNew);
            closeDatabaseInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

```
 public List<DatabasePlaylistObject> getPlaylists() {
        List<DatabasePlaylistObject> resultList = new ArrayList<DatabasePlaylistObject>();
        try {
            openReadableInstance();
            Cursor cursorNew = databaseInstance.rawQuery(SELECT_PLAYLISTS_SQL_QUESTION, null);
            if (cursorNew.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DatabasePlaylistObject tempPlaylistObject = new DatabasePlaylistObject();
                    tempPlaylistObject.setId(cursorNew.getInt(0));
                    tempPlaylistObject.setPlaylistName(cursorNew.getString(1));
                    tempPlaylistObject.setPlaylistData(cursorNew.getString(2));
                    resultList.add(tempPlaylistObject);
                }
                while (cursorNew.moveToNext());
            }
            closeDatabaseInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultList;
    }
```

```
 public void removePlaylist(int playlistId) {
        try {
            openWritableInstance();
            databaseInstance.delete(DatabaseDefinition.TABLE_SAVED_PLAYLISTS, DatabaseDefinition.COLUMN_ID_PLAYLIST + "=" + playlistId, null);
            closeDatabaseInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In MainActivity:

```
 private View.OnClickListener btnSavePlaylistListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (gridCustomAdapter.getPlaylistId() == -1) {
                String playlistDataTemp = new Gson().toJson(gridCustomAdapter.getCurrentPlaylist());
                dbHandler.insertNewPlaylist(currentSearchContent, playlistDataTemp);
                onSwipeRight();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You really shouln't create new tables outside of `onCreate` of the SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: `Create SQLite TABLES dynamically?` **Why?** Create all the needed tables in advance. Then fill them when needed.

Comment: All elements of the same type should go into the same table. If you need to differentiate them, add another column.